# Finding the $\lim \sup \cos (2\pi nx)$ for irrational $x$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x$ be an irrational number in $[0, 1]$. Find $\lim \sup \cos (2\pi nx)$

What I think  I need to do is in some way take an $\epsilon$ neighborhood around some arbitrary point close to $1$ and then show explicitly that the least upper bound is $1$ since the sequence in question gets arbitrary close to $1$.

What I need help with is setting up the necessary details to show what the lim sup is.